# How do I properly initialize these variables?

Tags: c++, initialization

**UPDATE 2:**

It is compiling now but still giving the same warnings.  I am stumped.

**UPDATE:**

Using these constructors had no effect, and still produces the same warnings.  From what I understand, this is how variables are initialized.  My guess is I am making a simple mistake as a beginner.

```
Ship::Ship()
{
    m_type[0] = '\0';
    m_engCnt = 0;
    m_engines[0] = {};
}

Engine::Engine()
{
    m_size = 0;
    m_type[0] = '\0';
}
```

**WARNINGS:**

```
Variable 'sdds::Ship::m_engines' is uninitialized.  Always initialize a member variable (type.6)

Variable 'sdds::EngineShip::m_type' is uninitialized.  Always initialize a member variable (type.6)

Variable 'sdds::Engine::m_size' is uninitialized.  Always initialize a member variable (type.6)

Using uninitialized memory 'invalid' -> MAIN.CPP  Line 50
Using uninitialized memory 'invalid' -> MAIN.CPP  Line 77

Buffer overrun while writing to 'this->m_engines':  the writable size is '400' bytes, but '480' bytes might be written.  -> SHIP.CPP Line 91
```

When I try to initialize the variables the way I see in the examples I have found, the compiler still generates warnings of uninitialized member variables on both Engine and Ship class.  I know this is causing further errors down the road.

Here is what I've tried:

```
// Ship.cpp

Ship::Ship() {   m_type = '\0';   m_engCnt = 0;   m_engines = {}; }

// Engine.cpp

Engine::Engine() {   m_size = 0.0;   m_type = '\0'; }
```

I still get the uninitialized variable warnings, and I know I am allocating memory improperly, since my overall program is failing some of the member variable validations.  It also keeps looping the same error message at the end when it does run.

Since I am still new to C++, I am having difficulty finding what I am doing wrong, and I'm sure that what I'm getting wrong is something blatantly obvious and stupid.  So I'd appreciate if you could point out the nose on my face so I can get unstuck!

My question is:

1. How do I properly initialize these variables?
2. Is there something obvious that I am getting wrong about the memory addresses/allocation?

Here is the offending code:

```
// Engine.h

#pragma once
#ifndef SDDS_ENGINE_H
#define SDDS_ENGINE_H

namespace sdds
{
    const int   TYPE_MAX_SIZE = 30;                 // Max length of the type attribute in Engine class.
    
    class Engine
    {
        private:
            double  m_size;                         // The size of an engine, as a floating point number in double precision.
            char    m_type[TYPE_MAX_SIZE + 1];      // The engine model type, as an array of chars of size TYPE_MAX_SIZE.

        public:
            Engine() = default;                     // Default constructor.
            ~Engine() = default;                    // Default destructor.
            Engine(const char* type, double size);  // Custom constructor that rx's as params: engine type, size.
            double get() const;                     // Query that returns the size of the engine.
            void display() const;                   // Query that prints to the screen the content of an object in the format [SIZE] - liters - [TYPE] <ENDL>
    };
}

#endif



---

// Engine.cpp

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Engine.h"

using namespace std;

namespace sdds
{
    Engine::Engine(const char* type, double size)
    {
        // Validate explicit params:
        if (size > 0 && type[0] != '\0')
        {
            // Assign params to engine:
            strcpy(m_type, type);
            m_size = size;
        }
    }
    
    double Engine::get() const
    {
        return m_size;          // Return size of engine m_size.
    }

    void Engine::display() const
    {
        // Detect if Engine members are valid:
        if (m_size > 0 && m_type[0] != '\0')
        {
            // If valid, display m_size at precision 2, m_type:
            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << m_size << " liters - " << m_type << endl;
        }
    }
}


---

// Ship.h

#pragma once
#ifndef SDDS_SHIP_H
#define SDDS_SHIP_H
#include "Engine.h"

namespace sdds
{
    const double    MIN_STD_POWER = 90.111;     // The minimum power of a ship, acc'g to the regulation.
    const double    MAX_STD_POWER = 99.999;     // The maximum power of a ship acc'g to the regulation.
    const int       MAX_NUM_ENGINES = 10;       // The maximum number of engines a ship can have.

    class Ship
    {
        Engine  m_engines[MAX_NUM_ENGINES];     // Statically allocated array of engines, of size MAX_NUM_ENGINES.
        char    m_type[TYPE_MAX_SIZE + 1];      // Ship model type, statically allocated arry of charss of TYPE_MAX_SIZE.
        int     m_engCnt;                       // The number of engines that are actually installed on the ship.

    public:
        Ship() = default;
        // ~Ship() = default;
        Ship(const char* type, const Engine arr[], int size);
        operator bool() const;
        bool operator<(double power) const;
        double calculatePower() const;
        void display() const;
        Ship& operator+=(Engine engine);
        
    };
    bool operator<(double power, const Ship& theShip);
}

#endif


---

// Ship.cpp

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include "Ship.h"

using namespace std;

namespace sdds
{
    //Ship::Ship()
    //{

    //}

    Ship::Ship(const char* type, const Engine engines[], int cnt)
    {
        // Validate params:
        if (type != nullptr && engines != nullptr && cnt > 0)
        {
            // If valid, store params in current instance:
            strcpy(m_type, type);           // Copy string from params to current instance of m_type.
            m_engCnt = cnt;                 // Current instance of m_engCnt is set to param cnt.
            
            // Iterate through current instance's m_engines[i] and assign engines[i].
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                m_engines[i] = engines[i];
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            // If params are invalid, set to a default empty state.
            m_type[0] = '\0';               // Default state for m_type = '\0'.
            m_engCnt = 0;                   // Default state for m_engCnt = 0.
        }
    }

    double Ship::calculatePower() const
    {
        double total_power = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_engCnt; i++)
        {
            total_power += m_engines[i].get() * 5;
        }
        return total_power;
    }

    void Ship::display() const
    {
        if (*this)
        {
            cout << "No available data" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << m_type << "-";
            cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout.precision(2);
            cout.width(6);
            cout << calculatePower() << endl;
            cout.unsetf(ios::fixed);
            cout.precision(6);
            for (int i = 0; i < m_engCnt; i++)
            {
                m_engines[i].display();
            }
        }
    }

    Ship::operator bool() const
    {
        // Explain in the reflection what happens if the keyword explicit is removed, and why is it necessary.
        bool valid = true;
        m_type[0] == '\0' && m_engCnt == 0 ? valid = false : valid = true;
        return valid;
    }

    Ship& Ship::operator+=(Engine engine)
    {
        // Make sure the number of engines is less than max allowed:
        if (m_engCnt < MAX_NUM_ENGINES)
        {
            if (m_type[0] == '\0')
            {
                cout << "The object is not valid! Engine cannot be added!" << endl;     // Output error message.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_engines[m_engCnt + 1] = engine;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool Ship::operator<(double power) const
    {
        bool result = false;
        calculatePower() < power ? result = true : result = false;
        return result;
    }

    bool operator<(double power, const Ship& ship)
    {
        bool result = false;
        ship.calculatePower() > power ? result = false : result = true;
        return result;

    }

}


---

// Main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Ship.h"
#include "Ship.h"
#include "Engine.h"
#include "Engine.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sdds;

void printHeader(const char* title)
{
    char oldFill = cout.fill('-');
    cout.width(40);
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "|> " << title << endl;

    cout.fill('-');
    cout.width(40);
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout.fill(oldFill);
}

int main()
{
    {
        printHeader("T1: Testing Constants");

        cout << "TYPE_MAX_SIZE: " << sdds::TYPE_MAX_SIZE << endl;
        cout << "MIN_STD_POWER: " << sdds::MIN_STD_POWER << endl;
        cout << "MAX_STD_POWER: " << sdds::MAX_STD_POWER << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T2: Testing Default Constructor");

        Ship invalid;
        invalid.display();
        invalid += Engine("D2", 2.1);
        cout << endl;
    }

    Engine engines[] = {
        Engine("V8", 4.4),
        Engine("V8", 5.0),
        Engine("Inline", 4.1),
        Engine("D3", 7.0),
        Engine("D0", 2.0),
        Engine("D1", 3.2),
    };

    {
        printHeader("T3: Testing Custom Constructor");
        
        Ship titanic("cruiser", engines, 6);
        titanic.display();
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T4: Testing Conversion to Bool Operator");
        Ship invalid;
        Ship titanic("liner", engines, 1);

        if (invalid)
            cout << "1. Test Failed! Object should be invalid.\n";
        else
            cout << "1. Test succeeded!\n";

        if (titanic)
            cout << "2. Test succeeded!\n";
        else
            cout << "3. Test Failed! Object should be valid.\n";
        
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T5: Testing += and < Operators");

        Ship titanic("liner", engines, 3);

        char type[]{ "D0" };
        while (titanic < sdds::MIN_STD_POWER)
        {
            type[1]++;
            cout << "Ship not up to standard. Required power: "
                 << sdds::MIN_STD_POWER << endl;
            titanic += Engine(type, 2.1);
        }

        titanic.display();

        if (sdds::MAX_STD_POWER < titanic)
            cout << "Too much power." << endl;
        else
            cout << "Ship doesn't exceed power regulation of: "
                 << sdds::MAX_STD_POWER << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to read this official help page: [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You mentioned you are getting warnings but you haven't included them in your post. Could you please add them?

Comment: When you defined the default constructor for the classes `Ship` and `Engine` (as you stated in your question), did you also remove the `= default` from the class definitions? If not, then this the compiler-generated default constructor may be overriding the default constuctor you wrote.

Comment: You may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Obviously I used the debugger already.  Did you read the part where I said I am a beginner and have exhausted my limited knowledge?

Comment: My statement about using a debugger was related to your statement in your question that your program is no longer producing any warning messages, but is now not producing the expected output. Meanwhile, you have edited that statement out of your question.

Comment: You can test whether your intended constructor is being executed by either (1) inserting a `printf` line into it, or (2) setting a breakpoint in your debugger. However, the `printf` trick may not work if your program is not terminating normally (due to buffering), therefore it may be safer to use `fprintf( stderr, "constructor is being called\n" );` instead.

Comment: Your constructors are assigning rather than initializing. You either need to use [a default member initializer or a member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) to initialize class member variables. Recommended reading: [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: Also you contstructors have multiple paths.  The Ship::Ship(const char* type, const Engine engines[], int cnt) ctor else clause doesn't initialize the m_engines, which is likely the cause of one of your warnings.  Check your control flow.

Comment: The initializeShip() function is called by the default constructor and the engines are initialized there.

Comment: Note: Due to a nearly complete lack of curation on the Internet the bad and truly bad tutorials greatly outnumber the good and excellent tutorials, so it's pretty much dumb luck when you're learning from a good tutorial unless you already know enough about whatever you're trying to learn in order to recognize a good tutorial when you see one. With C++ it is vitally important to inoculate yourself against bad tutorials, and the best way to do that is with [good reference materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You might want to review [ask]. The current form of the question starts with something that is not the question, which is a big turn-off. You lose readers that way. Someone reading the question for the first time is not going to understand your updates with nothing introducing them. (Not to mention that sections labeled "update" are usually a bad sign. Most clarifications should be made "inline" and not in a separate section.)

Comment: 1) I see no `initializeShip` function. 2) you misunderstand what initialization means in C++. The only time you can initialize a variable is when it is created. `int a; a = val;` does not initialize. It assigns. `int a = val;` initializes. For class member variables you can't always `int a = val;` because you won't know what value to use for `val` until an object is constructed. This is what the Member initializer list is for.

Comment: void Ship::initializeShip()
 {
  m_type[0] = '\0';
  m_engCnt = 0;
  m_engines[m_engCnt];
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_ENGINES; i++)
  {
   m_engines[i].initializeEngine();
  }
 }

Comment: char m_type[0] = '\0';
  int m_engCnt = 0;
  Engine m_engines[m_engCnt];

If I do this it generates errors.

Answer (score 1):

Check your control flow.

```
    Engine::Engine(const char* type, double size)
    {
        // Validate explicit params:
        if (size > 0 && type[0] != '\0')
        {
            // Assign params to engine:
            strcpy(m_type, type);
            m_size = size;
        }
    }
```

What happens for the else conditions?  m_type nad m_size are not initialized.  Why can't you just set m_type = '/0' and m_size = 0?

```
        Engine::Engine(const char* type, double size)
    {
        // Validate explicit params:
        if (size > 0 && type[0] != '\0')
        {
            // Assign params to engine:
            strcpy(m_type, type);
            m_size = size;
        }
        else
        {
            m_type = '/0';
            m_size = size;
        }
    }
```

The same applies for all of your other warnings.  You need to make sure all construction happens for each path.

So when looking at the Ship class check the ctor for control flow as well.

Also, you set m_engCnt only in the ctor for Ship.  The problem is that you allow adding engines (which should increase this count as well).  You need to account for that.

```
Ship& Ship::operator+=(Engine engine)
{
    // Make sure the number of engines is less than max allowed:
    if (m_engCnt < MAX_NUM_ENGINES)
    {
        if (m_type[0] == '\0')
        {
            cout << "The object is not valid! Engine cannot be added!" << endl;     // Output error message.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m_engines[m_engCnt + 1] = engine;
        m_engCnt++;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Note that no initialization is actually done in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't initializing the member variables. You are assigning to them *after* they are automatically initialized with garbage.

There are two ways to initialize class member variables:

1. C++11 Default member initialization
2. Member Initializer lists

I prefer both as this is the intent of the default member initialization. Use default member initialization so defaulted constructors work as expected and have sane values and user-defined constructors just need to override the variables they are directly taking in as arguments.

```cpp
//Note: Both of these are redundant. Pick one.
#pragma once
#ifndef SDDS_ENGINE_H
#define SDDS_ENGINE_H

namespace sdds
{
    const int   TYPE_MAX_SIZE = 30;                 // Max length of the type attribute in Engine class.
    
    class Engine
    {
        private:
            double  m_size{0.0};                         // The size of an engine, as a floating point number in double precision.
            std::string    m_type{};      // The engine model type, as an array of chars of size TYPE_MAX_SIZE.

        public:
            Engine() = default;                     // Default constructor.
            ~Engine() = default;                    // Default destructor.
            Engine(const char* type, double size);  // Custom constructor that rx's as params: engine type, size.
            double get() const;                     // Query that returns the size of the engine.
            void display() const;                   // Query that prints to the screen the content of an object in the format [SIZE] - liters - [TYPE] <ENDL>
    };
}

#endif

    Engine::Engine(const char* type, double size)
    : m_size(size)
    , m_type(type ? type : "") //Don't pass a nullptr to std::string's C-string constructor.
    {}
```

Comment: Minor quibbles: The member initilizer list predates c++11. It's been around pretty much since the beginning. default member initialization started showing up in C++11.

Comment: @user4581301 Fixed.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the following line:

```
 Engine  m_engines[MAX_NUM_ENGINES];
```

But you never actually allocated memory for the engine array. So the problem is that remember when you declare an int array, you need to do something like:

```
int* foo = new int[size of array];
```

I would avoid static array in this case, because you do not know how many ships are going to be added.

There is still another problem:
Again you intialized your m_engines as an array that will store Engine objects but:

```
m_engines[0] = {};
```

You are setting the first element of an object type of Engine with a string???? That looks very suspicious to me....

Comment: I think you need to clarify the opener a bit more. `Engine  m_engines[MAX_NUM_ENGINES];` Is allocating storage, so it's not clear what you mean here. The second part is heading in the right direction. Obviously from the error received later , `MAX_NUM_ENGINES` isn't big enough and some sort of dynamic allocation makes sense, but `vector` is a better answer since it easily resizes as items are added.

Comment: Well it really depends on your perspective, vector is good if you are not concerned with performance and just want to do something with c++. But in more advanced courses, I recommend using a linked list or a dynamic array for the extra performance effeciency.

Comment: Note that traversal of a linked list can be slow due to the lack of spatial locality and the added pointer chasing. It is only high performance for insertion and deletion if you don't have to seek to the insertion or deletion point. The speed difference between a vector and a manually managed array is questionable. The only difference between the two in optimized code is the time spent initializing the `vector`, a trade-off I gleefully take for the reduced memory management.

Comment: Well the linked list is faster if the size is changing a link, also it looks like he does not need a lot of random access, so just a tail or a head pointer is enough, note the for linked list if the size can be changed so it saves memory for truly massive collections, and it also saves time because you do not need to copy the elements to a new array when it is full.

Comment: He is clearly learning the language.  Shouldn't we just point him in the direction of standard containers like std::vector in this case?  They grow when needed and you don't have to worry about out of bounds and the like.

Comment: Doesn't int* foo = new int[size of array] have the same issues of Enginer m_engines[MAX_NUM_ENGINES] here?  What should the size be for the new?

Comment: Well the important thing is that when the array is full you can easily go foo = new int[size of array*2] and copy the contents to that one......

Comment: Yes, but you are repeating the work that `vector` does for you, you are likely to insert bugs that `vector` doesn't have the first few times you write the allocate-and-copy routine, and there is really groovy stuff with `realloc` and placement `new` in the `vector` that often eliminates the need for the reallocation and copying. Really smart and experienced men and women from around the world have been tuning `vector` implementations for decades. Can you write something better? Sure, but you're going to have to work at it and it's probably going to be specialized for one use-case.

Comment: Yep well I am just pointing out that if you need effiency vector is not the best choice in a lot of situations, also there is a reason why linked lists exist.....

Comment: Going to drop a bit of reading that, especially with the video it talks about, illustrates the point I'm trying to make: https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists .

Comment: This time I did downvote the answer. The opening statement still doesn't make any sense.